# How to start an activity after selecting an item from a list?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I want to select an item from a list. When this item is clicked, I want to open a new activity and have the related item shown in the next activity. This is the code for my click listener:

```
listView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
    String item = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
    public onClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // Getting item text to be able to show it in a toast.
        String item = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddPlaneActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol adapterview.
And on the onClick method: invalid method declaration, return type required

Comment: why do you have `String item = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);` twice ? the one outside the `onClick` method does not know the `adapterView `. It probably is what you error comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
        { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddPlaneActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Item", item);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

with `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`  in layout

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application):

#### Initial Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddPlaneActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_STUFF_HERE", item);
startActivity(intent);
```

#### Access information from that intent on next activity:

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_STUFF_HERE");
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. The onClick method keeps complaining about not having a return type.